# rsyslog forwarding to different port

Tags: rsyslog, forwarding

I am receiving syslog logs over port 513 that I am trying to forward to port 514 (where I have a service listening for them). So far, all my attempts have been unsuccessful.
I've tried making a file in /etc/rsyslog.d/ with

```
:fromhost-ip, isequal, "10.20.0.1" @127.0.0.1:514
```

I've tried adding a ruleset to the /etc/rsyslog.conf file:

```
ruleset (name="to514"){
    action(type="omfwd" Target="127.0.0.1" Port="514" Protocol="udp")
    }
input(type="imudp" port"513" ruleset="to513")
```

What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: In your rule you declared `Target="127.0.0.1"` which is localhost. So what you're doing is, you're sending logs from your local computer to your local syslog server on your computer. Can you further explain what you're trying to do? Because this currently doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @eDonkey That's exactly what I'm trying to do. For whatever reason, the client can't send logs over 514, so I had to provide an alternate port. 513 was the lucky winner. I have a service that will pull logs from relevant syslog facilities, but I don't know of a way of assigning a facility to the logs from that source other than by getting the logs over 514.

Comment: Please try to explain what exactly you're trying to do. I don't understand it. Why would you want to log your local logs to a local syslog server - on the same client?

About the problem with the opened/closed ports, please check if your firewall is running: `sudo firewall-cmd --state`

Comment: @eDonkey They aren't local logs. The client is a separate device. It's sending logs over 513 to the syslog server. The client is unable to send logs over 514. Those logs are collected by the syslog server and sent to a cloud service for parsing. The agent on the syslog server responsible for delivering the logs to the cloud is able to collect logs by syslog facility. Logs don't seem to be assigned a syslog <facility>.<severity> when received over port 513. Instead, they're assigned <server_name>.who. This means I can't collect and ship them to the cloud service.

Comment: So, the problem is not, that you're not receiving the logs, it's that they're in the wrong format (not syslog format)? || Please check if your firewall is running - that would explain a lot about the open/closed port